# redirect any link to specific url (.htaccess)

Tags: .htaccess

I want to redirect
/public/courses/((anything)) to /courses

this is my code , it does not working

```
Redirect 301 /public/courses/.* /courses
```

How can I explain any link to .haccess file?

Answer (score 0):

Please try following htaccess Rule. Make sure to place this rule top of your htaccess Rules file.

Please clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteRule ^public/courses/.*$ /courses [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I cleared my browser cache
but does not working

Comment: @ElaineYousef, I have edited my Rules set now, please check it once and let me know if this helps you?

Comment: @ElaineYousef, could you please do let me know if this has worked for you?

Comment: but when i tried (one section) as 
RewriteRule ^anyword/.*$ /courses [R=301,L] 
its work! but
RewriteRule ^anyword/anyword/.*$ /courses [R=301,L] 
RewriteRule /anyword/anyword/.*$ /courses [R=301,L] 
--- not working ! i dont know why

Comment: @ElaineYousef, Please do let me know on 2 questions: 1st- what is sample url you are hitting? 2nd- Do you have any other rules also apart from these?